# How to update UI for callback received while app is in background?

Tags: java, android, reflection, mvp

I am creating an android application using MVP architecture. I have created Presenter and Interactor classes. I am struggling to update UI when app is in background and comes back to foreground.

Let's consider following scenario.

Button on UI is clicked and presenter is notified about it. Presenter asked Interactor to provide data from backend. By the time Interactor provides result to presenter somehow UI is in background. How can I save the state of it and change UI components once app is in foreground.

I tried doing following things:

1. Using flags (turn on the flag and check in onResume to call the method that supposed to be called when callback received. But problem is that let's say if I have 5 different services that can be called by presenter which has different callback then I will require 5 flags which I don't like it)
2. Using JAVA reflection (Store the name of method be called in HashMap with parameter)

Is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: Subscribe to a BehaviorRelay or reactive database which gives you the response that is relevant to your currently displayed data at any time you subscribe to its initial state or future changes

Comment: @EpicPandaForce can you share any example?

Answer (score 0):

As name MVP Suggests Model View Presenter
Model : Model is responsible for getter setter methods also known as POJO.
View : Contains activities/fragments with views.
Presenter : Actual Business Logic where you can communicate network calls OR relate with backend databases such as SQLite / MySql.

When button click you need to call presenter which will perform background tasks once it is done you need to notify your view that the response is Success/Failure via CallBacks which done with the help of interfaces.

Example:

```
interface BaseContract {
        interface BaseView {
            //Methods for View
            void onDoSomething();
        }

        interface BasePresenter {
            void doSomething();

        }
    }

    class BaseMainPresenter implements BaseContract.BasePresenter {
        BaseContract.BaseView view;

        BaseMainPresenter(BaseContract.BaseView view) {
            this.view = view;
        }

        @Override
        public void doSomething() {
            if (view != null)
                view.onDoSomething();
        }
    }

    class DemoClass implements BaseContract.BaseView {

        //Create object of Presenter 

        /****
         * Example :
         * BaseMainPresenter baseMainPresenter = new BaseMainPresenter(this);
         */
        @Override
        public void onDoSomething() {
            //Deal with Context here.
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You could add some "pause" logic to your presenter:

- Whenever the UI goes to background, you tell the presenter to "pause" and to save any data being received to a cache (could be as simple as a list inside your presenter).
- Whenever the UI is back to foreground, you tell your presenter to unpause and to unload its cache to the UI (if the cache list is not null it pushes it to the UI, just like a regular response received by your interactor)